# node dotenv files not loading for test env

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I have two dotenv files, one for development and another for test.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

if (process.env && process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  dotenv.config({path: '.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV});
} else {
  dotenv.config({path: '.env.development'});
}

const http = require('http');
const app = require('../src/app');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8000;
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Here are my questions:

When does server load dotenv files in my case? If I run in `test` env, why do I get undefined for those process.env variables? 
It seems to me this file only runs once, when I change NODE_ENV, it does not change which file to load.

So in short:

My development dotenv is working, but just having trouble when changing it to `test` dotenv

Comment: That should work. Perhaps it's how you run your setup. Perhaps ensure you are getting the correct path for `console.log('.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV)` when running in test mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I have multiple .env files?
>
> No. We strongly recommend against having a "main" .env file and an
>   "environment" .env file like .env.test. Your config should vary
>   between deploys, and you should not be sharing values between
>   environments.

From [dotenv documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#faq)

Comment: How can I load the .env in testing env then?

Comment: For those trying to use items in .env file inside of jest, follow this. Make sure your path to your .env file is from the starting point of your test file. And you may have to restart your terminal for changes to take affect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781150/jest-test-not-reading-environment-variables-with-dotenv

Answer (score 22):

Please consider using [dotenv-flow](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow) *(an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow))*.

**dotenv-flow** extends *dotenv*, adding support of `NODE_ENV`-specific `.env*` files *like `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.stage`, and `.env.production`,* and the appropriate `.env*.local` overrides.

It allows your app to have multiple environments *(like "development", "test", "stage", and "production" respectively)* with selectively-adjusted environment variable setups and load them dynamically depending on the current `NODE_ENV`.

In addition to that, `.env*.local` overrides add the ability to overwrite variables locally for development, testing, and debugging purposes
*(note that the appropriate `.env*.local` entry should be added to your `.gitignore`)*.

So, as you can see, **dotenv-flow** has a slightly different approach to managing `.env*` files under version control. Please refer the [Files under version control](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow#files-under-version-control) section to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

`custom-env` also solves this problem, it allows multiple configurations file for different environments. `npm install custom-env`.
 You can also specify which `.env` file to use on the go. `require('custom-env').env('test');`.

Full Docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-env

Comment: There are plenty another solutions, question is `dotenv` specific.