# Jest test not reading environment variables with dotenv

Tags: node.js, jestjs, dotenv

I'm running a test on a function that calls for environment variables, I'm getting undefined.
Solutions I tried and didn't work:

1/ add `require('dotenv').config({path:'../.env'})` in my test file

2/ pass globals in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "USER_ENDPOINT":"xxx",
      "USER_KEY":"xxx"
  }
}
```

3/ pass my variables in test command in package.json

```
"test": "USER_ENDPOINT:xxx USER_KEY:xxx jest --watchAll --detectOpenHandles"
```

4/ added an Object.assign in a beforeEach() in my test file

```
beforeEach(() => {
        process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {USER_ENDPOINT:"xxx", USER_KEY:"xxx" });
});
```

and got the error "Jest encountered an unexpected token"

5/ I created a jest.config.js file on the root

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'./.env'});
module.exports = {
    globals: {
        USER_ENDPOINT:"xxx", 
        USER_KEY:"xxx"
    }
};
```

Most of these solution were suggested here:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/193
but none of it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works as expected using `dotenv` package to load environment variables.

E.g.

`index.test.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') });

describe('61781150', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(process.env.USER_ENDPOINT).toBe('http://localhost:3000');
    expect(process.env.USER_KEY).toBe('abc123');
  });
});
```

`.env`:

```js
USER_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:3000
USER_KEY=abc123
```

Most likely you need to get the path of the `.env` file through the `path.resolve` method.

Unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61781150/index.test.js (8.236s)
  61781150
    ✓ should pass (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.264s, estimated 11s
```

Comment: `require("dotenv").config("./.env")` also works.