# TypeORM migration entries lost from DB, `migration:run` re-runs them, then fails with "relation already exists"

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, database-migration, typeorm

I have a [NestJS app with TypeORM, dockerized](https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter/tree/ee7abf6d481b1420708e87dea3cb99ca110cc168). I have `synchronize` turned off, using migrations instead. In the container entry point, I do `yarn typeorm migration:run`. It works well the first time around, and according to the logs it inserts records into the `migrations` table.

I noticed that when I start the project the next time it often tries to re-run migrations and fails (as expected) due to "relation already exists". At this point I can verify that entries are indeed missing from the `migrations` table via `docker-compose exec db psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations"`. The DB schema is up to date. When I insert a new record manually it gets an incremental ID *after* the missing records. So the records were there at some point.

I can't figure out what might cause entries in the `migrations` table to disappear (be rolled back?). This happens on the project linked above. It's a straightforward example project. I don't have an entity accidentally named "migrations". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running specs that synchronized the DB was the issue.

I had a `.env.test` to use a different DB, but as it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520869/node-dotenv-files-not-loading-for-test-env) that is not supported by `dotenv`. There are a [few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259025/using-env-files-for-unit-testing-with-jest/54282600) to make it work. I chose `dotenv-flow/config` and added it to my test script:

`jest --collect-coverage --setupFiles dotenv-flow/config`

Answer (score 0):

As a *workaround* I currently insert into the `migrations` table manually:

```
docker-compose exec db psql -U postgres -c "INSERT INTO migrations (timestamp, name) VALUES ('1619623728180', 'AddTable1619623728180');"
```